# Abrir janela modal automaticamente ao abrir a página

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando usar a função .load do jquery, substituindo a .click. Porque a intenção é que a lightbox abra ao carregar a página e não clicando.

JS PARA ABRIR A JANELA MODAL AO CLICAR NUM LINK

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();

      var id = $(this).attr("href");

      var alturaTela = $(document).height();
      var larguraTela = $(window).width();

      //colocando o fundo preto
      $('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
      $('#mascara').fadeIn(1000); 
      $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

      var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
      var top = ($(window).height() / 3) - ( $(id).height() / 3 );

      $(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
      $(id).show(); 
    });

    $("#mascara").load( function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $(".janelao").hide();
    });

    $('.fechar').click(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      $("#mascara").hide();
      $(".window").hide();
    });
  });
```

JS PARA ABRIR A JANELA MODAL COM O CARREGAMENTO DA PÁGINA

Nessa parte alterei o $("a[rel=modal]").click por $(window).load e FUNCIONOU! Porém só abre o fundo preto e não a div #janelao

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load( function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
```

Daí em $("#mascara").click( function(){ tentei inserir o .load e $(window).load no lugar do .click e .show no lugar de .hide e NÃO funcionou

```
     $("#mascara").load( function(){
      $(this).show();
      $(".janelao").show();
    });
```

Então o meu problema é carregar a div janelao que não carrega, só carrega o fundo preto

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema está na variável `id`

Ao trocar de `$("a[rel=modal]").click(` para `$(window).load(` você altera o valor do `this` e, por isso, ao realizar a operação `var id = $(this).attr("href");` essa variável fica com valor alterado.

Altere essa atribuição para var `id = $("a[rel=modal]").attr("href");` que irá funcionar.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta Felipe. Por fim eu utilizei essa solução http://wbruno.com.br/jquery/abrir-modal-tuto-maujor-automaticamente-ao-carregar-pagina-jquery/

Comment: valeu amigo.. é isso mesmo.. esta dica me ajudou muito